# Mongodb/Meteor: combine documents with ids in many arrays(returned by another query)

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I am using meteor to make a query( for a publication) to find all the `Results` generated by `Workers` which has finished their work:

`Results` has the following structure:

```
result example 1:
{
  _id: "sldf234sdf"
  result_a:0,
  result_b:0
}

result example 2:
{
  _id: "ghjwef23qql"
  result_a:0,
  result_b:0
}
```

`Workers` is defined as:

```
{
  _id: "iweyr23s"
  results:["sldf234sdf", "ghjwef23qql"], //here is a list of 
  tag:'running'
}
```

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
// 1), I want to find all the workers which is finished with their tag
const workers = Workers.find({tag:'done'});

// 2), I want to get the resultid arrays in all the workers, then combine it into a big array
const results_id_arrays = workers[0].results + workers[1].results + ...

const results = Results.find({_id:{$in: results_id_arrays }});
```

So, my question is, how to make a mongodb query to implement the second step?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mighty `underscorejs` for this. There is also a meteor package for it. Check documentation [here](http://underscorejs.org/).

```
//fetch results
const workers = Workers.find({tag:'done'}, {results: 1, _id: 0}).fetch();
//pluck only the ids, without field name
const plucked = _.pluck(workers, 'results');

//use plucked ids to find results
return Results.find({_id:{$in: plucked }});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

you can get results ids like this:

```
const results_id_arrays = Workers.aggregate({$project:{a:'$results'}},
                         {$unwind:'$a'},
                         {$unwind:'$a'},
                         {$group:{_id:'a',res:{$addToSet:'$a'}}}).map(function(e) {return e.res})
```

and then

```
const results = Results.find({_id:{$in: results_id_arrays }});
```

does this work?